# How to query for 2 mandatory matching record in same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to validate 2 mandatory record in same column in SQL Server?

```
@Declare @GivenMonth datetime='2017-03-01'
```

I have declared a date and need to check whether table contains 2 preceding record with `PaymentStatus = 'Y'` and `Month = @GivenMonth`:

```
id | Month       | PayamentStatus 
---+-------------+----------------
 1 | 2017-01-01  | Y
 2 | 2017-02-01  | Y
 3 | 2017-03-01  | Y
 4 | 2017-04-01  | Y
```

I have used this code but it's not working:

```
SET @FirstPrecCovMonth = DATEADD(month, -1, @GivenMonth) 
SET @SecondPrecCovMonth = DATEADD(month, -2, @GivenMonth)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PaymentRecord 
           WHERE PaymentStatus = 'Y'
             AND (CoverageMonth = @FirstPrecCovMonth
             AND CoverageMonth = @SecondPrecCovMonth))
BEGIN
    //////////////////////////////
END
```

Comment: Please do *not* use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: Sure I will remember  next time. My mistake it got added.

Answer (score 2):

Your `IF EXISTS()` is looking for a row where the CoverageMonth column has two different values, which isn't possible.

You instead need to do two `IF EXISTS()`, since you want to know if a FirstMonth exists AND a SecondMonth exists.

So in psuedocode:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT using @FirstMonth)
AND EXISTS(SELECT using @SecondMonth)
  BEGIN ...
```